How do you reconcile Hashem knows everything from knowing himself and your thinking
BH
Hi so Rambam says Hashem knows everything from knowing himself Yesodei Torah 2:10, so when he does the action of knowing is this keter or daat?
Also how do you reconcile our knowing with Hashem's?  As in, when Hashem is doing the knowing what am I? As in, who are you and me when Hashem is doing the knowing?
I heard we also have the bechina of keter and daat so how do you reconcile our thinking with hashems thinking when your explain everythin with sephirot?
Also, how do you explain keter and daas in regards to the person as what is this when you explain this regarding man how do you reconcile them together just when man is doing the thinking alone?

VTC, you ask too many vague questions in one.

The knowledge Rambam speaks of, according to the Tzemach Tzedek1, is the sefira of Da'at of Atzilut. Hashem creates us through the knowledge itself.
After the world of Atzilut, there are lower worlds of Beriya, Yetzira and Assiya, and in those worlds, Hashem is hidden to the point that beings can feel like they are "other" to Him2.
The keter and da'at of man is a mashal of a mashal of His.
Who are we? We are Hashem's "zulato"3, whom He gave a Neshama and Guf. That Neshama and Guf receive their life and vitality from Hashem Himself. He gives us free will - to choose to do a Mitzva or not - and gives us the feeling that we are in control of the actions that flow from our decisions. However, that's an illusion. We decide what to do, including the actions of "knowing" and "desiring" (da'at and keter), and Hashem makes what happens next actually happen.
How can we say we exist if we are simply living an illusion? That's a very good question, i.e. who are we? What is a "zulato"? We may have no power, but we do have freedom. We should thank Hashem with all our heart and soul that not only did He create us with this freedom, but also allows us to exercise it, by lending us His power whenever we need it, bechol yom tamid.
How can we exist if He is the true existence? That's the Tzimtzum in a nutshell. I once heard it explained like this4 - if Hashem was not metzamtzem His desire for us and for us to do the Mitzvot, we would indeed be overwhelmed. Like a very controlling father, we would not have a chance to be truly "someone else", and become our own person. It is thanks to the Tzimtzum, where Hashem hides His overt and infinite Ratzon from us, to "give us room" to flourish and do the Mitzvot ourselves, and thus become an existence of our own.

1. Derech Mitzvotecha Haamanut Elokut 5 - Mahadura Batra
2. Ibid. 11
3. See this shiur.
4. See this shiur.
